# M13Checkbox set Mixed CheckState on click

Tags: ios, swift, checkbox

I try to implement a [M13Checkbox](https://github.com/Marxon13/M13Checkbox) in tableViewCell.

I implemented a method responding to "ValueChanged" event but if I call `sender.setCheckState(.Mixed, animated: false)` in this method, the display of the checkbox is `.Checked`.

However if I do `print(sender.checkState)` the state of the checkbox is `.Mixed`.

Anything that i'm missing ? Do i use the write event?

Thanks for your help !

edit:
Event present in OptionsViewController:

```
  @IBAction func optionCheckChange(sender: M13Checkbox) {
    let rowPoint = sender.convertPoint(sender.frame.origin, toView: self.optionsTableView)
    let indexPath = self.optionsTableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(rowPoint)  
    sender.setCheckState(.Mixed, animated: false)  
    print(sender.checkState)
  }
```

OptionTableViewCell code:

```
import UIKit
import M13Checkbox

class OptionTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  // MARK: Properties
  @IBOutlet weak var checkbox: M13Checkbox!
  @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!


  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
  }

  override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you called `setCheckState` on the main thread?

Comment: Yes it is called from the main thread. Like i said in the post, it is directly called in a method responding to the  "ValueChanged" event.

Comment: Could you try to share the code for your cell? Also, what happens when you scroll through the list of cells, are they being reset for reuse properly?

Comment: Post edited with event method code and cell code, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Oh and the check state is set in the cellForRowAtIndexPath if the row (an option in that case) is part of an option list.

Comment: I just tried implementing the most simplest case, which would be `@IBAction func optionCheckChange(sender: M13Checkbox) {
        sender.setCheckState(.Mixed, animated: false)
    }` and that works fine for me. It prints `Mixed` in the console and has a dash in the UI. Does your problem occur when you start scrolling?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116833/discussion-between-kumuluzz-and-azartys).